# Keep a Google Maps v3 Map hidden, show when needed

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way of preventing a Google Maps (JS, v3) map being displayed from the get-go? I'm doing some pre-processing and would like to show my 'Loading' spinner until everything is good to go (more eloquently put, hide the map -- e.g. the container `div` – until all pre-processing is complete – at which point, show the map).

Hooking up the map's `idle` event doesn't help that much, since the map is already displayed when this event hits.

I know that the container `div` gets inline-styled by GMaps after loading, my first idea was to clear out the `style` attribute (whilst listening to the `idle` event), but it would be interesting to see if there is a way of creating the map and not displaying it until all pre-processing is done.

Maybe by using an argument to the `new google.maps.Map` constructor, or a `MapOption` ?

Any thoughts on this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've used a $("#map_canvas").attr("style", "position:relative; visibility: hidden") trick, works.

Comment: As Dr1Ku says.  Render the Map to an invisible div, then show the div on the first idle event.  Be sure to use addListenerOnce.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Also remember to call:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

if you have changed the size of the `<div>`.  A `display:none` `<div>` has no size.

Comment: This was only a partial solution for me. I also had to call `map.fitBounds(bounds);` where bounds was the proper LatLngBounds object.

Comment: In additon to what matt said, you can use `panTo(location)` to re-center the map.

Comment: @dtanders what a great addition!

Answer (score 5):

Or you could just hide it like with css visablility or css opacity.

```
$("#GoogleMap").css({ opacity: 0, zoom: 0 });
initialize();

google.maps.event.addListener(map,"idle", function(){ 
     $('#Loader').hide();
     $("#GoogleMap").css({ opacity: 1, zoom: 1 });
});
```

Comment: opacity:0 did the trick, i was trying to display:none, and didnt had good results

Answer (score 4):

This works for me. I'm using the JQuery library.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Checkbox').click(function(){
        $('#googleMapDiv').toggle();
        initialize(); // initialize the map
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Gabriel. Thanks for this amazingly simple and effective solution. Works like a charm!

Comment: Please note, that this will probably reload the map every time, and with maps API v3 there is a daily limit to how many times you may load the map element.

Answer (score 3):

another way to show the hidden map when map is first time rendering the `<div>` is to set style: visibility.

When firstly hidden, use `visibility = hidden`; to show use `visibility = visible`

the reason is: [visibility:hidden means that the contents of the element will be invisible, but the element stays in its original position and size.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp)

Answer (score 2):

this works fine for me, I use jquery tabs

```
setTimeout(function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(default_lat, default_lng));
        map.setZoom(default_map_zoom);
    }, 2000);
```

om this link https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1448

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function ()
    {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

better way:

```
gmap.redraw = function() {
    gmOnLoad = true;
    if(gmOnLoad) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(gmap, "resize");
        gmap.setCenter(gmlatlng);
        gmOnLoad = false;
    }
}
```

and in show click event:

```
$("#goo").click(function() {
  if ($("#map_canvas").css("display") == "none") {
    $("#YMapsID").toggle();
    $("#map_canvas").toggle();
    if (gmap != undefined) {
        gmap.redraw();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I thought that this temporary solution is better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

depending on what you are doing another posibility could be to have multiple bools you set to true when each process is done.

For example:

if you have a geocode service running which you want to wait for, you could have a var called
GeoState

and in the result part of the geocoder set GeoState to true,
then have a timed function check if all the services have returned true, when they have, make the map visible.